# string.Format -- Dividing two objects?

Tags: c#, string.format

I'm pretty unfamiliar with C# and I'm trying to make sense of some source code I need to work with. I've done some Googling, but I'm drawing a blank on this one. It almost seems like this statement is taking the `toString()` of two objects and dividing them... for a numeric value??? Does that even make sense?

```
return string.Format("{0}/{1}", base.GetType().FullName, this.Operation);
```

Operation, as it turns out, is a string `operation == "Write"`

I think I know the type of `base.GetType()`

Comment: Could you please provide result of the operation and explain what is unclear about it. So far it looks like you think `string.Format("Bring me beer")` should make glass of beer immediately appear on the table...

Answer (score 1):

{0} says "put the first thing in the argument list here", {1} is the next item, and so on.  So that string.Format() is the same as:

```
return string.Concat(base.GetType().FullName, "/", this.Operation);
```

It's not trying to divide anything or return a number, C# isn't nice like that for you.  Anytime you want to get a number, you're gonna have to tell C# to parse it.

Comment: Thanks. my next question was whether it would do arithmetic if they were originally numbers, but that answers it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it does not divide but generates a new string composed of the two objects (as strings) separated with the character `/`.

If `base.GetType().FullName() == "MyType"`, then the result will be the string `"MyType/Write"`.

Answer (score 1):

String.Format only replaces the {0} and {1} placeholders by the string values of the parameters (so the FullName and the Operation values). It does not do any arithmetics like dividing the two values, even if they were originally integers.

Answer (score 0):

All it does is returns a formatted string where {0}, {1} and so forth are substituted with argument values, for example:

```
System.String/Write
```